# Constructing mongodb queries on collection via input field

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a players collection with 'first name' and 'last name' fields.

I'm looking to search on the above collection and have an input field doing the search. Thats working fine to search on first name $or last name. But I want to be able to search on both.

I read on an answer to another question to combine the two as an array. I've done that, but it still searches either or.

```js
 return Players.find({ playerSearch_index: new RegExp(search, 'i')};
```

Sample Document:

```js
 {
firstName: "David",
lastName: "Smith",
playerSearch_index: [David,Smith],
location: "London",
Country: "England",
score: 0
}
```

Search is just via < input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchbox"  />

An example search is 'David' which should return all Davids.
'Smith' should return all Smiths
David Smith should return all who are 'David' + 'Smith'

It runs on keyup:

```js
 Template.searchbar.events({
'keyup #searchbox': function(evnt, tmpl){
  Session.set('search', $('#searchbox').val());
}
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include a sample document and `search` value?

Comment: Thanks Johnny, updated.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a third field "fullname" and searching it with:

```
return Players.find({ fullname: { $regex: new RegExp(search, 'i')}});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well :

let's say you want to look for "martin" in both fields

```
var query = new RegExp(search,'i');

return Players.find({$or:{[{firstname:query},{lastname:query}]}});
```

If you want to look for "john doe" in both fields, you will do

```
var queryArr = value.split(" ");//value is "john doe"

//we delete the empty string "" or we will get a * (all) query
queryArr = _.compact(queryArr);

queryArr = queryArr.map(function(queryStr){
  return new RegExp(queryStr,'i');
  }
);
return Players.find({$or:{[{firstname:{$in : queryArr}},{lastname:{$in : queryArr}}]}});
```

//edit : was not functionning correctly with query string with trailing whitespace

Comment: That begins to work now, however I run into something else which is more of a meteor thing I guess... it works, on the first word, then I press space and it shows all results again, until the next letter is typed and then it filters by second word. Any idea?